# Do I need to know any other language before starting with javaScript in unity for game development?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, programming-languages

I just want to know if I should know any other programming language before starting 
to use javaScript in unity 3d for game development

Comment: You should use C#. See: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/08/11/unityscripts-long-ride-off-into-the-sunset/

Comment: "It’s been with us since Unity 1.0, but its time is finally coming: we have begun the deprecation process for UnityScript, the JavaScript-like scripting language available as an alternative to C# in Unity today."

Answer (score 1):

There is no JavaScript in Unity. There used to be something like JavaScript but that was a lookalike scripting language and it is being phased out, no longer works in the new version of Unity. You should learn C#.